# How to write a list of lists into a single CSV file in R?

Tags: r, list, csv

I have a list of lists and I want to write each individual list into individual  row of a single csv file in R. A simple exapmle is given below:

```
l1 = list("aa", "bb", "cc")
l2 = list("xx", "yy", "zz")
myList = list(l1, l2)
```

So, `myList = [["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["xx", "yy", "zz"]]`, and I would like to write each of the 2 lists in a row of a csv file.

Comment: how do you want this to look in the csv? can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Thanks! @G.Grothendieck however this gives me a columnwise format. which of course can be easily converted to row-wise with: write.csv(t(sapply(myList, unlist)))

Comment: @MattW. I want "aa", "bb", "cc" in the first row and "xx", "yy", "zz" in the second row of the csv file.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck's answer above should do that.

Comment: Try   `write.csv(t(sapply(myList, unlist)))`

Comment: yep... as I mentioned above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hang on for dear life...here comes the "never use `plyr`" crowd... BUT...

```
> new_list <- plyr::adply(myList,1,unlist,.id = NULL)

> new_list

  V1 V2 V3
1 aa bb cc
2 xx yy zz

> write.csv(new_list, "mycsv.csv")
```